# Jenkins stop/start system service

Tags: jenkins, centos7

Hi all in my Jenkins pipeline I need to stop a system service, copy latest file across then restart the service again. I am stuck at stopping system service step.

Operating system is CentOS and Jenkins is running under user 'jenkins'.

Following accepted answer in this post (https://serverfault.com/questions/772778/allowing-a-non-root-user-to-restart-a-service) I created a new group, added 'jenkins' into that group then updated sudo list via 'visudo'. Now user jenkins can stop/start that service on Putty command line like this: `sudo systemctl stop <my-service>`

When I updated pipeline file like below

```
                sh "echo stop Linux service"
                sh "sudo systemctl stop <my-service>"
```

I got following error:

```
+ echo stop Linux service
stop Linux service
[Pipeline] sh
+ sudo systemctl stop <my-service>

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

If I remove sudo in pipeline then I got this error:

```
+ echo stop Linux service
stop Linux service
[Pipeline] sh
+ systemctl stop <my-service>
Failed to stop <my-service>: Interactive authentication required.
See system logs and 'systemctl status <my-service>' for details.
```

How can I achieve my goal please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a user to the sudoers group only allows them to invoke `sudo`. They still need to authenticate using their password. Since you're not running this command over a TTY, you can't be asked your password, so sudo says "Nuh uh."

The obvious solution, then, is to make sure that your Jenkins agent user doesn't need a password to invoke sudo at all. You can do that by adding `NOPASSWD` to that user in `/etc/sudoers`.

Run `visudo`, and set the line to something like:

```
jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```